# App crashes when start an Activity inside scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: android

I'm making a simple alarm clock app and now I'm having problem with the service which checks if the current time matches the set time and starts another activity. Here's the code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID){
    hourSet = intent.getIntExtra("hourSet", 0);
    minuteSet = intent.getIntExtra("minuteSet", 0);
    checkTime();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void checkTime(){
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {         
        public void run() {
            time.setToNow();
            currentHour = time.hour;
            currentMinute = time.minute;

            if(currentHour == hourSet && currentMinute == minuteSet){
                Intent i = new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmTime.class);
                startActivity(i);
                cancel();
            }

        }
    }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL   );
}
```

I have debugged the service, everything is fine until the `if` statement. When the current time matches the set time, the app crashes.
So how to fix this ?

Comment: can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: I don't think you can start an activity inside a thread. Your app would be crashing with an IllegalStateException. You can't have a background thread control UI actions.

Comment: @Prateek *inside service thread (not activity thread)

Comment: Thanks to the guy below, I added i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); and it worked. Since you're mentioning Logcat, I guess I'll have to learn much more. Just got started learning Android a few weeks ago. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why people dont include catLog?
Problem is you are trying to start activity on service task, which is not possible, but if you add magic code like
   `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

before `startActivity` call, it starts on the new task and everything should work just fine :)

Comment: Thanks.
Actually I'm a total newbie.
Just got started learning a few weeks ago.
So sorry for any dumb mistake :(

Comment: Dont be sorry, we are here to help you :) Logcat is just log of the android system, you can see output of it in the eclipse android monitor. If my answer was helpful, please accept it clicking the green check :)

Comment: I tried using it and I was very surprised that it said exactly what I had to do. I'll definitely looking into it more. Thanks again though, green check checked. :D